# Hide text input field on page load?

Tags: php, javascript, input, textbox

it's should be something really simple if its possible. anyway of doing so? can't seem to find it online.

i have a set of checkboxes and textboxes beside it. i only want the textboxes to appear if i check it. my ids are dynamic using php so i cant use javascript out of the loop.

the code below is to test if it works to hide. i am able to hide on click but iam hoping to do the other way round.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><input name='CBox $TBCounter' type=\"checkbox\" value=\"{$row['type']}\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('TBox $TBCounter').style.visibility='hidden';\"/></td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>
                <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"mytext\" id=\"TBox $TBCounter\"></td><br />
                            </tr>";
                $TBCounter++;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript's `window.onload` to make something run every time the page loads.

---

Before your loop...

```
$elementsToHide = array();
```

During your loop, put this

```
$elementsToHide[] = $TBCounter;
```

Then make your script (after the loop) look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        <?php foreach ($elementsToHide AS $TBCounter): ?>
        document.getElementById('TBox <?php echo $TBCounter ?>').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        <?php endforeach ?>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: $TBCounter is a running variable. possible to put that chunk of code in the loop?

Comment: Just store `$elementsToHide = array()` and add to it each loop: `$elementsToHide[] = $TBCounter`, then at the end of the loop, write the script out, and loop over `$elementsToHide` to duplicate the lines you're hiding - updated the answer

Comment: thank you so much! this works perfectly. one last qns if you don't mind, any chance for unselect event for checkboxes? unselect to hide textbox.

Comment: Come again? Not quite sure I get what you mean.

Comment: if i check the box, a textbox will appear by the side now. if i uncheck it, any ways to hide the textbox?

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" onclick="document.getElementById('something').style.visibility=(document.getElementById('something').style.visibility=='hidden'?'visible':'hidden')"` should work, just change `something` as the ID.

Comment: `<input name='CBox $TBCounter' type=\"checkbox\" value=\"{$row['type']}\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('TBox $TBCounter').style.visibility=(document.getElementById('TBox $TBCounter').style.visibility=='hidden'?'visible':'hidden')/>` did i get it wrong? it's not working for this..

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better (read: less intrusive) ways, but the simplest is probably to set the visibility of the element to hidden and change your Javascript to make it visible.

So, add `style="visibility:hidden;"` to the textbox element and change the javascript to set `.style.visibility = 'visible'`

Editing your code, that would be:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input name='CBox $TBCounter' type=\"checkbox\" value=\"{$row['type']}\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('TBox $TBCounter').style.visibility='visible';\"/></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>
    <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"mytext\" id=\"TBox $TBCounter\" style=\"visibility:hidden\"></td><br />
                </tr>";
    $TBCounter++;
}
```

As per Joe's comment, this will not work for users with javascript disabled as the field if hidden when the page loads. One way around this is to set the field invisible in javascript by outputting an inline script tag.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input name='CBox $TBCounter' type=\"checkbox\" value=\"{$row['type']}\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('TBox $TBCounter').style.visibility='visible';\"/></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>
    <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"mytext\" id=\"TBox $TBCounter\"></td><br />
                </tr>
    <script>document.getElementById('TBox $TBCounter').style.visibility='hidden';</script>";
    $TBCounter++;
}
```

A third (better) alternative could be to set a class for the textboxes and use javascript to hide all elements with that class on page load.

Comment: Except that doing this means that anyone with JS disabled can never complete your form, as you hide the fields immediately - much better to leave them visible and hide them on page load with JS

Comment: I agree, hence the note about there being less intrusive ways. Echoing a script tag might be one way around it for example.